# Disabling creation of contact from lightning for outlook

Tags: lightning, lightning-outlook

I have enabled lightning for outlook, but contacts are not created by users manually. So I want to disable the functionality of creating contacts in lightning for outlook. Currently I don't see any option to disable that. Is there any way by which we could disable adding email users as contacts in salesforce.

Or else

Is there any identifier on contact by which I would be able to identify whether the contact is coming from Lightning for Outlook and put a validation rule to prevent it.

Comment: I think this is a global action - you can delete it